# Can I use ImageSharp with .Net Core for a screen capture of the web browser

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, imagesharp

I have an Asp.Net Core 2.2 MVC web app. It is setup as multi-tennant and running on Azure.

In order to improve support options I want to add the possibility for the user to create a screen capture of the browser window that is then attached to an e-mail sent to the support desk. (sending of the e-mail is already part of the solution)

As the application is hosted in the cloud I don't know what devices the users are/will be using, it can be PC's (Windows, Mac ...) or tablets (smartphones are technically possible but due to the nature of the application very unlikely) so it shouldn't be tied in with the browser or OS.

After searching around I found ImageSharp, which is cross-platform, but I haven't found any reference to a possibility to make a screen shot.

Is anybody aware if this is possible? If so, a short code sample would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageSharp is a 2D Graphics API. Screen Capture is an operation that will require an embedded web browser and falls well outside of the goals of the library.